# Android's new project structure

Tags: android, maven, build, gradle

I have a question regarding Android's new build system Gradle.

The [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide) suggests to put your project and libraries in the same root folder. But in my opinion this doesn't make sense in some cases.

Usually I set up my projects like this:

```
Project folder (Git repo of my company)
-- Main project
---- src (etc)
-- Local Library 
---- src (etc)
```

If I needed a library from another repository, I saved it somewhere else on my hard drive. In the end the Main project was build with Maven on a Jenkins. Does Gradle allow to add a library from another location, e.g. if the library isn't available in Maven Central? Or do I really need to save the library underneath the Project folder?

```
Project folder (Git repo of my company)
-- Main project
---- src (etc)
-- Local Library 
---- src (etc)
-- Library from another Git repo
---- src
```

As you can see, a Git repo would be in another Git repo.

How do you handle dependencies, which are not available in a Maven repository? How do you attach the same local library to different projects without copying them?